# IBM Cloud and terraform: How to create and download API key?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, ibm-iam, terraform-provider-ibm

With the [IBM Cloud provider plug-in for terraform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-getting-started) it is possible to [access the current authentication token](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-iam-data-sources#iam-token).

```
data "ibm_iam_auth_token" "tokendata" {}
```

I have also successfully created a service ID.

```
resource "ibm_iam_service_id" "serviceID" {
  name        = "test"
  description = "New ServiceID"
}
```

How can I create an API key, download it and use it to run the next `terraform apply` under the service ID?

Comment: Doesn't this answer that? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-classic_keys

Comment: @pijemcolu Not sure how that relates to API keys for IAM service IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recent update, the feature of [creating and referencing an API key for a service ID was added](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/iam_service_api_key).

### **OLD**

The task is a little bit tricky because the plugin does not return the [**iam_id** for service IDs, only the unique ID](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-iam-resources#iam-service-id).

There are two options. One is to use NULL resources with **curl** and **jq** to

1. first GET the service ID details, including the iam_id,
2. then, via POST, to create the API key.

A snippet for 1. could look like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "devops_iam_id" {
  // Get iam_id for service ID
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -X GET 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/v1/serviceids/${ibm_iam_service_id.myServiceID.id}' -H 'Authorization: ${data.ibm_iam_auth_token.iam_tokendata.iam_access_token}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | jq '.iam_id'"
  }
}
```

Another option is to make use of the fact, that the iam_id seems to be simply the prefix `iam-` followed by the unique ID. Thus, the following works for me:

```
// Create a service ID for devops tasks
    resource "ibm_iam_service_id" "myServiceID" {
      name        = "myServiceID"
      description = "ServiceID for deploying the app and devops tasks"
    
      // create and download API key
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "curl -X POST 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/v1/apikeys' -H 'Authorization: ${data.ibm_iam_auth_token.iam_tokendata.iam_access_token}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ \"name\":\"henrikTestKey\", \"iam_id\":\"iam-${ibm_iam_service_id.myServiceID.id}\", \"store_value\": true}' > apikeyOutput.json"
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: With this [recent release](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm/releases/tag/v1.13.0), the **iam_id** is returned and can be directly addressed:

```
// Create a service ID for devops tasks
    resource "ibm_iam_service_id" "myServiceID" {
      name        = "myServiceID"
      description = "ServiceID for deploying the app and devops tasks"
    
      // create and download API key
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "curl -X POST 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/v1/apikeys' -H 'Authorization: ${data.ibm_iam_auth_token.iam_tokendata.iam_access_token}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ \"name\":\"henrikTestKey\", \"iam_id\":\"${ibm_iam_service_id.myServiceID.id}\", \"store_value\": true}' > apikeyOutput.json"
      }
    }
```

The necessary Bearer token can be obtained using the [IAM token data source](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-iam-data-sources#iam-token):

```
data "ibm_iam_auth_token" "tokendata" {}
```

Comment: Snippet also in https://gist.github.com/data-henrik/e652b45e250ae95e26dc8b2367ba7201